# Ardour5 (or Ardour6) do not display any GUI windows

Tags: xfce, window-manager, ardour

Either running from terminal or from menu. ardour windows do not appear

I've tried ardour5 and ardour6 (built from source)

Yet, if I create a new account it seems to work fine.

I've removed all of $HOME/.config and cannot seem to reset whatever appears to be persistent user state.

This seems like some issue with the Window Manager because if I:

```
$ xwininfo -root -tree  | grep ardour
 0x5200001 "ardour-6.2.120": ("ardour-6.2.120" "Ardour-6.2.120")  10x10+10+10  +10+10
```

This shows something tried to display, I've tried force mapping this with xdotool but it's just a black window, obviously some interaction with window events is borked.

I've tried: ardour --sync with same results.

Here is what the terminal launch shows, no errors....

```
$ ardour6
bind txt domain [gtk2_ardour6] to /usr/local/share/ardour6/locale
Ardour6.2.120 (built using 6.2-120-g13f041536d and GCC version 9.3.0)
Ardour: [INFO]: Your system is configured to limit Ardour to 1048576 open files
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading system configuration file /usr/local/etc/ardour6/system_config
Ardour: [INFO]: CPU vendor: GenuineIntel
Ardour: [INFO]: AVX-capable processor
Ardour: [INFO]: CPU brand:       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
Ardour: [INFO]: Using SSE optimized routines
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading plugin meta data file /usr/local/share/ardour6/plugin_metadata/plugin_tags
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading default ui configuration file /usr/local/etc/ardour6/default_ui_config
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading 449 MIDI patches from /usr/local/share/ardour6/patchfiles
Ardour: [INFO]: Loading color file /usr/local/share/ardour6/themes/dark-ardour.colors
```

Answer (score 1):

On the working account, ardour attempted to open the file $HOME/.gtkrc-2.0 and then tried a bunch of $HOME/.gtk-2.0/* things. These all failed, then ardour continued on...

On the failing acount .gtkrc-2.0 was able to be opened. It never moved on from there.

To make things align I took the fairly hammer approach of:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gtk*
```

ardour5 and ardour6 startup fine after that.